# Unable to create retry-able datasource for spring boot jdbc

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-retry

I would like to add the retry feature for database connection certain number of times until the app acquires it. For the I have used the spring-retry on the `DataSource` but it is not working. It is throwing the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JdbcTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExistingValue must be an instance of com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

I have seen the debug logs but those are not helpful. Here is the sample [source code](https://github.com/maradanasai/retry-db-conn-demo) . kindly help

Note: the dependencies mentioned in build.gradle is required for my app. I have only extracted the retry part.

Comment: The problem is you are replacing existing datasources too early (`beforeInit`) where you should use the latter `afterInit`. However what is your usecase here? Why would you need a retry on the `getConnection` seems like the wrong place and it should be part of your datasource instead (like HikariCP, which already has some connection refresh support).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Use case is if the application starts before the db server, it will fail with error. so I would like to retry for connection until the db server ready. Earlier I have tried with ```afterInit``` but didn't worked out. Now it is working with ```afterInit``` and not sure why. Can you elaborate the second part please?

Comment: Use the [`DatabaseStartupValidator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseStartupValidator.html) for that and ditch your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use-case is delaying the start of Spring Boot until your database is up. Spring actually ships with a component that does that. The [`DatabaseStartupValidator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseStartupValidator.html) is that component and has existed since about Spring 1.x.

You can add it as a bean and it will wait for further bootstrapping until the database is up.

```java
@Bean
public DatabaseStartupValidator databaseStartupValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
    var dsv = new DatabaseStartupValidator();
    dsv.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return dsv;
}
```

For a more detailed explanation see [this blog post of mine](https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/).

Comment: Wow, your blog post made it work for me, thanks a lot! Seems it is the only source on the Internet that explains DatabaseStartupValidator and especially the trick with the BeanFactoryPostProcessor!